# Left out join return more rows without unique primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw many questions but nothing helped for me.

Is there any ways I can join with duplicated primary keys?

I know primary keys must be unique but possible primary keys from my tables are duplicated.

I have two tables

TableA

```
ID   Position    Title            Security_Code     Security_Name 
1      100      Engineer               200               A         
2      101      Scientist              201               B
2      101      Scientist              201               B
3      102      Analyst                202               C
4      103      Teacher                203               D
5      104      Assistant              204               E
```

TableB

```
ID  Position   Title        City     Country  Skill  Security_Code  Security_Name  tag   industry
1     100      Engineer     Tokyo     Japan   C++          200           A         003    EV            
2     101      Scientist    Portland  US      Analysis     201           B         001    Private      
2     101      Scientist    Portland  US      Analysis     201           B         002    Finance
5     104      Assistant    Boston    US      Excel        204           E         001    Private
5     104      Assistant    Boston    US      Excel        204           E         002    EV
5     104      Assistant    Boston    US      Excel        204           E         005    Public
5     104      Assistant    Boston    US      Excel        204           E         006    Finance
5     104      Assistant    Boston    US      Excel        204           E         008    Education
```

With those two tables, I want to use Security_Code as primary key since I want to find City and Country corresponding to Security_Code. However, neither security_code nor ID (Which is supposed to be unique) unique

What my trials are

```
select A.ID, A.Position, A.Title, A.City, A.Country, Skill, A.Security_Code, A.Security_Name
from TableA as A
left outer join
TableB as B on TableA.ID =TableB.ID and TableA.Security_Code = TableB.Security_Code
```

or

```
select A.ID, A.Position, A.Title, A.City, A.Country, Skill, A.Security_Code, A.Security_Name
from TableA as A
left outer join
TableB as B on TableA.ID =TableB.ID and TableA.Security_Code = TableB.Security_Code
```

or

```
select A.ID, A.Position, A.Title, A.City, A.Country, Skill, A.Security_Code, A.Security_Name
from TableA as A
outer apply
( select * from TableB as B
  where B.Security_code=A.Security_Code) B_
```

I would like to have

```
ID   Position    Title       City      Country   Skill    Security_Code     Security_Name 
1      100      Engineer     Tokyo      Japan    C++         200               A         
2      101      Scientist    Portland   US       Analysis    201               B
2      101      Scientist    Portland   US       Analysis    201               B
3      102      Analyst      Seattle    US       NULL        202               C
4      103      Teacher      Toronto    Canada   NULL        203               D
5      104      Assistant    Boston     US       Excel       204               E
```

But closest output table is

```
ID  Position   Title        City     Country   Skill   Security_Code  Security_Name  
1     100      Engineer     Tokyo     Japan     C++       200           A                   
2     101      Scientist    NULL      NULL      NULL      201           B              
2     101      Scientist    NULL      NULL      NULL      201           B
3     102      Analyst      Seattle   US        NULL      202           C
4     103      Teacher      Toronto   Canada    NULL      203           D         
5     104      Assistant    NULL      NULL      NULL      204           E         
5     104      Assistant    NULL      NULL      NULL      204           E         
5     104      Assistant    NULL      NULL      NULL      204           E         
5     104      Assistant    NULL      NULL      NULL      204           E         
5     104      Assistant    NULL      NULL      NULL      204           E
```

I am pretty sure that one of problems is primary key.
Also Tag and Industry in Table B.

Is there any way I can get my anticipated table?

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT ... rest of query?

Comment: Yes I have tried and It does not show me what I want..

Comment: Looks like a bad database design structure.  How deep into this project are you?  Data normalization and appropriate lookup tables would be more appropriate.

Comment: Select distinct would give you only one instance of id=5 and position 104  (and id =2) unless there are more columns which you are not showing.

Comment: I agree... The original tables have over 3 million rows in table A and around 1 million in table B. I just simplified it to ask you a question. Never handled this large database to normalize..

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Right.. But I need to have two  duplicated ID(2). distinct function gives me only one

Comment: I am not suggesting you normalize your table (which you really should.) But if you want a unique, nonduplicated, list of rows from your current tables add a distinct. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a distinct list of Security_Codes, you can use a Common Table Expression to get them.

Let me know if this is close:

```
with SecurityCode
as (
   select distinct
          Security_Code
        , City
        , Country
        , Security_Name
     from TableB
)
select TableA.Id
     , TableA.Position
     , TableA.Title
     , SecurityCode.City
     , SecurityCode.Country
     , TableA.Skill
     , SecurityCode.Security_Code
     , SecurityCode.Security_Name
  from TableA
  join SecurityCode
    on SecurityCode.Security_Code = TableA.SecurityCode;
```

Comment: Hello Brian Do you have a DBfiddle so that we can see how your solution works? What does the output look like?

Comment: No.. It does not show me what I want. I just edited my question because there should not be city and county in table A. I tried it as null as city ,null as country. Deleting two columns would affect your code?

Comment: I edited my answer for you

Comment: `union` implies `distinct`, it is not necessary to specify it again

Comment: @BrianStork I need some hours to get the final result since I have more than 3m rows. But It looks it is really close to my expectations! Thanks and I'll let you know when I get the correct output by accepting this answer!  I'll also run "inner join" with two tables. What should I add here?

Comment: If I add more columns into only tableB which are not inthis question, I thought I can simply put them into with securityCode  under distinct. However it is not working. Would it not be related to "tag" and "Write1" since above your code is being working almost properly?